# Formula for number of unorder pairs resulting from unique elements in k groups, excluding pairs of elements from same group k

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

I do not know how to solve the following problem, because combinatorics is not a strength of mine: I have a number of groups k, each of which has at least one element. All elements are different from one another. I want to know the total number of unordered pairs (i.e. of size 2) of all elements from all groups. BUT I do not want to include in that number those pairs which result from combining elements which belong to the same group k. I am looking for the correct terminology to describe and the right formula to solve these kinds of problems. Two examples below illustrate the problem and desired outcome. Your help is appeciated!

For example, group 1 consists of element a and b, group 2 of element c, group 3 of element d. The desired unordered pairs are: (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d). Ergo, there are 5 pairs. The pair that is excluded is the pair (a,b), because both elements belong to the same group.

Another example: group 1 includes a,b; group 2 includes c,d. The desired pairs are: (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d). The total number of pairs is 4. The pairs (a,b) and (c,d) are excluded because the respective elements belong to the same group.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: So where should it be posted?

Comment: You want to choose 2 groups (without replacement) from k groups, and then you want to take the product of the size of those groups. The notation for the set of combinations (without replacement) of a given size is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28343/notation-for-the-set-created-from-the-combination-or-permutation-of-a-set, over which you want to comprehend the size (the notation for a set comprehension and cardinality of a set is easy to look up), and finally you want to take a product of this, which is capital pi.

Comment: Also, this seems like a potentially relevant question for programming, if the aim is to write a function to determine the respective number of pairs etc.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Thank you! Unfortunately, I only understand the first sentence! I do n over k to determine the number of ways to combine two groups without replacement. Could you help me with the rest of it? Is there a preset formula for this kind of issue I could look at?

Comment: @Spaniel Here's the formula in LaTeX: https://i.imgur.com/p0cVRFp.png, hopefully that clarifies a bit. I'm not aware of an equivalent closed form expression in general, but depending on your set of groups, it may turn out that this analytic expression can be simplified to a function/closed form expression.

Comment: @Spaniel Actually upon further reflection that formula is wrong, sorry, because it is selecting a pair of groups and then trying to take the size of that. I think the correct formula is more like this: https://i.imgur.com/lOWyUPe.png

Comment: If all the groups have the same size `g`, then the formula gives us a straightforward answer: `g^2 * C(k, 2)`.

Comment: Note that in the formula I am using `G` to denote the set of groups, and not the number of groups, so `(G 2)` denotes the *set* of 2-combinations of groups (i.e. pairs of groups where the first and second group are not the same). We can only simplify this into an expression in terms of the *number* of 2-combinations of groups if we know something more about the groups, e.g. that they all have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You have groups G(1) .. G(K) where G(k) has N(k) elements
So you have

```
M = N(1) + .. + N(K)
```

elements in total, and can form

```
(M*(M-1))/2
```

2 element subsets. But this includes the ones you don't want, that have elements from the same group. There are

```
(N(k)*(N(k)-1))/2
```

such subsets from group k. So the number of subsets you want is

```
(M*(M-1))/2 - Sum{ k | (N(k)*(N(k)-1))/2}
```